# Would this shader code snippet still be converted as i.uv in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CzORVWFvZ28 to convert some code from ShaderToy to Unity. This is the shader that I'm attempting to convert: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Ws23WD.

I've going through the tutorial and I noticed that one of the changes to make is to take 'fragCoord.xy/iResolution.xy' and use 'i.uv' instead. But what if I had 'fragCoord.x/iResolution.x' and 'fragCoord.y/iResolutiony'? Does 'i.uv' replace both of those statements?

Here's how it appears in my code:

```
float2 uv = float2(fragCoord.x / iResolution.x, fragCoord.y / iResolution.y);
uv -= 0.5;
uv /= float2(iResolution.y / iResolution.x, 1);
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question correctly, but both multiplication and division in CG are component-wise, so dividing a float2 by a float2 is equivalent to dividing x and y separately.

Comment: @Piflik In the tutorial, he had a piece of code that was something like: 'float2 UV = fragCoord.xy/iResolution.xy) - .5'. And one of the shader to UV changes that he had to make was to replace it with: 'float2 UV = i.uv - .5'. But my code snippet above seems to separate the x and y coordinates; so in my case, how would I use 'i.uv' to replace the fragCoord/iResolution syntax?

Comment: @Piflik Would it just be: 'float2 uv = float2(i.uv)? And following the tutorial, I'm guessing that the third line is for aspect ratio, which I don't need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iResolution.x and iResolution.y refers to the pixel dimensions of the render window. In unity, you have _ScreenParams.x and _ScreenParams.y for screen pixel dimensions, but you only need to worry about this if you are rendering screen-space effects. If you want to render this as an effect on a plane, you use i.uv.x and i.uv.y instead for the same purpose. FragCoord / iResolution has the purpose of giving you the position of the fragment in the range of 0-1 on your screen, which is effectively equivalent to a UV-coordinate. Subtracting by 0.5 gives you the range -0.5 to 0.5.

The last line, uv /= float2(iResolution.y / iResolution.x, 1), is for correcting aspect ratio. If you are using an UV-mapped, square plane, you don't need to bother with this.

To summarize, these lines are equivalent to:

```
float2 uv = i.uv - (float2)0.5;
```